# How to non-interactively dump list of open buffers, associated filenames and saved/unsaved state?

Tags: elisp, buffers

I'm trying to develop a `git` hook that warns me if any files that belong to a repo are unsaved in the editor. For that I need a list of open files/buffers and their state, so basically a non-interactive version of `(list-buffers)`.

I run Emacs in server mode so I know I can do `emacsclient -e '(command)'`, but how do I dump the list of current buffers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`buffer-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html#index-buffer_002dlist-2189) returns a list of buffers. Call [`buffer-modified-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Modification.html#index-buffer_002dmodified_002dp-2168) to test if a buffer has been modified and [`buffer-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html#index-buffer_002dfile_002dname-2158) to test if a buffer is visiting a file.

The following snippet from the code of `save-buffers-kill-emacs` tests if there are any unsaved open files.

```
(memq t (mapcar (function
                  (lambda (buf) (and (buffer-file-name buf)
                                     (buffer-modified-p buf))))
                (buffer-list)))
```

Rather than enumerate all buffers, you may be better off testing only the buffers that are visiting files that are about to be committed. You can call [`find-buffer-visiting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html#index-find_002dbuffer_002dvisiting-2163) to get the buffer visiting a particular file, if any. Thus, given a list of file names in `filenames`:

```
(let ((unsaved 0))
  (mapc (lambda (filename)
          (let ((buffer (find-buffer-visiting filename)))
            (when filename
              (setq unsaved (1+ unsaved))
              (princ (concat "File not saved: " filename "\n")))))
        filenames)
  (when (> unsaved 0)
    (printc "There were unsaved files, aborting\n")))
```

In Emacs 24, it's possible to make `emacsclient` exit with a nonzero status, but this doesn't look easy: you have to [send the `die` command to the appropriate client](https://superuser.com/questions/295156/how-to-set-the-exit-status-for-emacsclient/542916#542916) of which there can be many. Anyway `emacsclient` could also fail because there's no running Emacs, which is a success condition for you. So I suggest to check whether `emacsclient` emits output on stdout.

```
files=
for x; do
  files="$files \"`absolute_path "$x" | sed 's/[\\\\\\\"]/\\\\&/g'`\""
done
unsaved=$(emacsclient -e '(let ((filenames ('"$files"'))) …)' 2>/dev/null)
if [ -n "$unsaved" ]; then
  echo "$unsaved"
  exit 1
fi
```